# UWP TeacHingTips and Navigation Issues

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm facing an issue when trying to implement a TeachingTip in a UWP App (1903 and later). Application is based on a NavigationView. TeachingTip is located in a View. When I navigate to the view for the first time everything work like a charm : TheachingTip is Diplayed as expected.
However as soon as I navigate in another view and then come back to the view which is embedding the TeachinTip a win32 unhandled exception is thrown.

[image]

As you can see above everytime i enter/quit the View containing the TeachingTip I make sure that TeachingTip is not opened as adviced in the following [xamlBrewer post](https://xamlbrewer.wordpress.com/2019/09/10/a-lap-around-the-winui-teachingtip-control/). unfortunately it has no effect.

I tried to Debug Mixed Code but there is only one error occuring indefinitely about TeachingTip CornerRadius.

I think this is a layout issue like the TeachingTip is not attached to a visualTree.

Any help would be appreciated.

Régis

Comment: Hello, can you provide a minimum runnable demo so that we can view your XAML layout and reproduce your problem.

Comment: I Richard, you can find a reproductible code in the following link : https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2295

Comment: Hello, I'm glad you found a solution, you can mark it, it will help more people with the same problem. In addition, I see that in Github, your question has already entered the processing flow. If this is a design defect of the control, the development team will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigations in Github Page [microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2295), it seems that when the property IsOpen is bound to a static datasource,the app crashes after navigation to a page if go back and then open the TeachingTip.

To Solve this problem, instead of triggering command, i implement Click Event. Inside Click Button event i change IsOpen Property value manually and I execute the ViewModelCommand

```
private void MenuFlyoutItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Offer_TeachingTip.IsOpen = true;
    var menuItem = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;
    if (menuItem.Command.CanExecute(menuItem.CommandParameter))
    {
        menuItem.Command.Execute(menuItem.CommandParameter);
    }
}
```

Not an ideal solution but it solved my problem.